# Select and insert BLOB Data in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, blob

I have following BLOB data saved in mssql database.

blob data image

[image]

I want to select this data and insert into another table using PHP.

flowing is my select query

```
$smt=sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT DATA from Docs 
where id = '001'");
```

I put this selected data in variable `$data` but not able to insert. Any idea how to handle situation like this?

insert statement

```
 $stmt_insert=sqlsrv_query($conn, "INSERT INTO newtable ([DATA]) VALUES 
                          ('$data')");
```

Comment: please add the insert part of your code too.

Comment: @yasoh insert statement added

Comment: Sounds like you don't know the error happening, do you get any from your php code? also if you don't already have add some error catching to your sql. check this for example http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php

Comment: What is your `DATA` column data type?

Comment: managed to do it please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to do it here is the code

```
$DATA=bin2hex($blobdata);
$DATAX="0x".$DATA;
```

then i use $DATAX as the variable to insert.